# JavaScript loose comparison between an object and a string

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

The below code,

```
var someObject = {"attr":1};   // line:1
alert(someObject == "someString");  //line:2
```

fails with the exception: `unexpected call to method or property access` in line 2.

When i change the comparison to a `strict` equals to, it works fine.

```
alert(someObject === "someString");
```

I understand that a doing a `strict` comparison does not do a `type conversion`, but am unable to determine at what point exactly is this error thrown when the type conversion happens.

**Note:** The exact object has around ten attributes and each attribute has a string value of significant length.

Minimal input with which i am able to reproduce this error:

```
someObject = {
 "a":"RESOLVED",
 "b":"A-1444779652190",
 "c":"{s=Hello, id=A-1444779652190}"
}
```

(`c` is a `string`, don't think it really matters here)

Comment: `alert(someObject == "someString")` alerts `false`

Comment: @Tushar - did you try in `IE 8` ? -

Comment: No, in chrome, please mention it in qustion

Comment: Oh, i have tagged it.

Comment: Tried in IE8, and it alerts `false` for me.

Comment: @Buzinas - Have added some additional note, please see if it may be useful.

Comment: Paste the exact object for us, then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `someObject == "someString"`, the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) does this:

> 9. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*x*) is Object and [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*y*) is either String or Number, return the result of the comparison [ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1)(*x*) ==
>      *y*.

When [ToPrimitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) is called with an object,

> Return a default value for the Object. The default value of an object
>   is retrieved by calling the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of the
>   object, passing the optional hint *PreferredType*. The behaviour of
>   the [[DefaultValue]] internal method is defined by this specification
>   for all native ECMAScript objects in [8.12.8.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8)

Summarizing, When [[[DefaultValue]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8) is called on a non-Date native object with no hint, it does this:

1. If the object has a `toString` method which returns a primitive, the default value is that primitive
2. If the object has a `valueOf` method which returns a primitive, the default value is that primitive
3. Throw TypeError

My guess is that some code modified [`Object.prototype.toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2) or [`Object.prototype.valueOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.4), and now they may throw when called by ToPrimitive.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed insight. Will check if these methods have been modified somewhere in the app.